# Updated RKRelationship Mapping with RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I've been diving into RestKit lately but since the newest version came out so recently, all the tutorials I've found both on their github and just on the web are all for old versions. Normally that's not a problem but a lot of classes that used to exist now don't, which of course, makes all the tutorials useless.

For the sake of everyone that uses it, for the newest version of RestKit, how would you relationship map this sample JSON?

```
{
"entities": {
    "message": [
        "dentist appointment"
    ],
    "dateRange": [
        {
            "start": "2012-11-15",
            "end": "2012-11-16"
        }
    ],
    "time": [
        "02:00:00PM"
    ]
},
"action": "REMINDER_SET",
"category": "REMINDER"
}
```

Upvote this if you have the same question.